# Leaflet geoJSON contextmenu

Tags: geojson, leaflet

I want to add a context menu on right click for various elements on my GeoJSON layer (I'm doing a road map so on a right click on the road at any part I want to show the context menu).

I've managed to get the left click working fine by using the onEachFeature and doing the following

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: showAssetInfo,
            contextmenu: contextreg
        });

    }   

 function showAssetInfo(e) {
        AssetMouseClick(e.target.feature.properties.objectid, e.latlng);
    }
```

For the context menu I have followed the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3L4c/12/)  . The context menu library is found [here](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/)

I have the following that gets called on the document ready (jQuery)

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: 'path.leaflet-clickable',
    zIndex: 99999,
    callback: function (key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
        "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
        "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
        "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
        "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
        "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
        "sep1": "---------",
        "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
    }
});
```

I've tested it and the selector does return the GeoJSON features, also if it attach the same menu to something else it works correctly.

Is there something I am missing here?

Also is there a good way to pass in the objectid to the menu when it starts up so I can use it when calling the different options of the menu

I have created this fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/Q3L4c/22/

Answer (score 3):

The event management for Leaflet and jQuery for this use case seems to conflict.

Instead of struggling with debugging, you should better use an alternate solution like this [contextMenu dedicated lib for Leaflet](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu).

Comment: Very powerful and efficient API for managing tooltips in leaflet, full support for GeoJSON features as well as inherited and dynamic context menu options.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out anything like [this](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html)

Comment: Yes that is the library I linked to above, am I missing something

Comment: I've been playing around with your jsfiddle example and getting nowhere. Pretty maddening. I'm more or less a newb with javascript but I was thinking of not using the plugin.It seems that the $.contextMenu is being ignored completely.